# In TextInputFormat in hadoop mapreduce what is byte offset? and how key is as byte offset and value is as content of line?

Tags: hadoop

While going through the CustomInputFormat topics i came to know we have some default inputformats like TextInputFormat, KeyValueInputFormat,SequencefileInputFormat and NlineInputFormat.

For TextInputFormat the line is read from the records and byte offset of line is used as key and content is used as value. What is this Byte Offset and how the content of line is considered as value please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

**TextInputFormat** is the default InputFormat . Each record is a line of input. The key, a
LongWritable , is the byte offset within the file of the beginning of the line. The value is
the contents of the line, excluding any line terminators (e.g., newline or carriage return),
and is packaged as a Text object. So a file containing the following text:

```
On the top of the Crumpetty Tree
The Quangle Wangle sat,
But his face you could not see,
On account of his Beaver Hat.
```

is divided into one split of four records. The records are interpreted as the following

**key-value pairs:**

```
(0, On the top of the Crumpetty Tree)
(33, The Quangle Wangle sat,)
(57, But his face you could not see,)
(89, On account of his Beaver Hat.)
```

Clearly, the keys are not line numbers. This would be impossible to implement in general,
in that a file is broken into splits at byte, not line, boundaries. Splits are processed
independently. Line numbers are really a sequential notion. You have to keep a count
of lines as you consume them, so knowing the line number within a split would be
possible, but not within the file

However, the offset within the file of each line is known by each split independently of
the other splits, since each split knows the size of the preceding splits and just adds this
onto the offsets within the split to produce a global file offset. The offset is usually
sufficient for applications that need a unique identifier for each line. Combined with
the file’s name, it is unique within the filesystem. Of course, if all the lines are a fixed
width, calculating the line number is simply a matter of dividing the offset by the width.